# How to set a xml in a SOAP xml request element

Tags: xml, soap, soapui

I have the following SOAP XML request. I want to check this request on SOAPUI. One of the element is a XML. I don't know how to set the XML in this element. When I set the xml I get an error.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sw="http://sw.ayudaaei.magrama.es" xmlns:fun="http://funcionario.sede.magrama.es">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<swSmiley Surprisedperacion>
<sw:xml>

</sw:xml>
<sw:numeroRegistro>20180020001040</sw:numeroRegistro>
<sw:fechaRegistro>16/05/2018</sw:fechaRegistro>
<!--1 or more repetitions:-->
<sw:listaDocumentos>
<fun:idDocumento>?</fun:idDocumento>
<fun:idRepositorio>?</fun:idRepositorio>
<fun:idTipoDocumento>?</fun:idTipoDocumento>
<fun:nombre>?</fun:nombre>
</sw:listaDocumentos>
</swSmiley Surprisedperacion>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The element   is the following XML. I don`t know if I can to set this XML in the element

```
 <DatosFormulario>
    <Titulo>PruebaJJ</Titulo>
    <Prioridad>1</Prioridad>
    <AreaPrincipal id="2">AGRICULTURA</AreaPrincipal>
    <AreaSecundaria id="3">fertilizantes</AreaSecundaria>
    <ProductosTFUE>
    <Seleccion>0</Seleccion>
    <No id="1">Forestal</No>
    </ProductosTFUE>
    <Producto id="2">PRODUCCIÓN VEGETAL - Cultivos herbáceos: Forrajes</Producto>
    <Ayudas16.1>
    <Seleccion>0</Seleccion>
    <Numero />
    <Nombre />
    </Ayudas16.1>
    <Ayudas16.2>
    <Seleccion>0</Seleccion>
    <Numero />
    <Nombre />
    </Ayudas16.2>
    <Miembro1>
    <Nombre>Juanjo Muñoz</Nombre>
    <Nif>11111111H</Nif>
    <Periodo1>1</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>2</Periodo2>
    <Importe>3</Importe>
    </Miembro1>
    <Miembro2>
    <Nombre>Juanjo García</Nombre>
    <Nif>11111111H</Nif>
    <Periodo1>3</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>4</Periodo2>
    <Importe>7</Importe>
    </Miembro2>
    <Miembro3>
    <Nombre />
    <Nif />
    <Periodo1>0</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>0</Periodo2>
    <Importe>0</Importe>
    </Miembro3>
    <Miembro4>
    <Nombre />
    <Nif />
    <Periodo1>0</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>0</Periodo2>
    <Importe>0</Importe>
    </Miembro4>
    <Miembro5>
    <Nombre />
    <Nif />
    <Periodo1>0</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>0</Periodo2>
    <Importe>0</Importe>
    </Miembro5>
    <Miembro6>
    <Nombre />
    <Nif />
    <Periodo1>0</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>0</Periodo2>
    <Importe>0</Importe>
    </Miembro6>
    <Miembro7>
    <Nombre />
    <Nif />
    <Periodo1>0</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>0</Periodo2>
    <Importe>0</Importe>
    </Miembro7>
    <Miembro8>
    <Nombre />
    <Nif />
    <Periodo1>0</Periodo1>
    <Periodo2>0</Periodo2>
    <Importe>0</Importe>
    </Miembro8>
    <ImporteTotal>10</ImporteTotal>
    <ImporteTotalPeriodo1>4</ImporteTotalPeriodo1>
    <ImporteTotalPeriodo2>6</ImporteTotalPeriodo2>
    <ImporteAnticipo>5</ImporteAnticipo>
    </DatosFormulario>
```

How can I set this XML to the element ?

Comment: It is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715404/soap-ui-how-to-pass-xml-inside-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SOAP-UI - How to pass xml inside parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715404/soap-ui-how-to-pass-xml-inside-parameter)

Comment: In order to keep XML data inside another XML, you can use CDATA.